# Запись в бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql, api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в данном примере,
данные из массива записывать в бд.
В массив они попадают из API в ходе цикла

```
<?php       foreach($page->getResult() as $resultItem){
    echo    "<div class='block'>Name: " . $resultItem->name .
            "<br>dateone" : " . $resultItem->{'volume:-1:0:1'}.
            "<br>datetwo" : " . $resultItem->{'volume:-1:0:2'}.
            "<br></div><hr>";
```

?>

```
        var     int       int
```

База имеет вид id - name - dateone - datetwo
нужно чтоб добавлялись туда построчно.
Методы которые я использовал ранее выдают ошибку, признаться я не знаток PHP, но возникла проблема, вроде не сложная, а ошибки выдает.

Comment: Что значит как записывать в бд? Создать SQL-запрос, исполнить его. Если вы не знаете как в php работать с базами данных - интернет полон руководств, писать вам в ответе еще одно - пустое занятие.

Comment: Не пустое ли занятие было писать вам этот комментарий, уважаемый.

Comment: Данные для отправки в бд, это `$resultItem->name`, `$resultItem->{'volume:-1:0:1'}`, `$resultItem->{'volume:-1:0:2'}` ? В бд данные нужно отправлять в ходе цикла?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Заполните свои данные вместо пропусков
$host = '';
$dbname = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';
$tablename = '';
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

//Код ниже можно обернуть в цикл, либо как вам нужно.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$tablename.' (name, dateone, datetwo) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bindValue($resultItem->name);
$stmt->bindValue($resultItem->{'volume:-1:0:1'});
$stmt->bindValie($resultItem->{'volume:-1:0:2'});
$stmt->execute();
```